# Taproot block version

Tags: mining-pools, taproot, activation-mechanism

In block [681543](https://blockstream.info/block/000000000000000000009bad313710a4675333de721a56e76ad0bfc240dfc595) Slush Pool had mined the proper taproot signalling (bit 2 in block version) block but the version wasn't the default 0x20000004 with a version base 0x20000000 but 0x3fff0004. Does it make any difference? Why would they use a different version base (0x3fff0000) just for this block?

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate of one of these two: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/96397/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/105694/5406

Comment: Thanks, the ASIC boost may be the proper answer :)

Comment: If one of them answers your question, you can close it yourself as a duplicate by flagging