# Unknown new rules activated (versionbit 1) when running Core v22.0.0 on testnet

Tags: bitcoin-core, testnet, taproot

I have got "Unknown new rules activated (versionbit 1)".
[image: Screenshot of "Unknown new rules activated (versionbit 1)"]
I am running Bitcoin Core v22.0.0 on testnet.
This seems to be the last version as of today (April 17 2022).
I am running a taproot wallet created as per [this guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/r37ky5/howto_create_and_use_a_taproot_wallet_on_testnet/).
I have checked signatures and sha256 sums before installing bitcoin core.

Any ideas what is this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["New rules activated" warning after upgrading to 0.20.0](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/96396/new-rules-activated-warning-after-upgrading-to-0-20-0) or possibly [Impact: unknown rules (versionbit 2) have been activated](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/107733/13866)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I have read that and not sure whether it apply. I have a fresh new install. Bitcoin core is up-to-date . Reloading do not help. Warning stays.